# how to pass model object thymeleaf page to angular controller in java

Tags: java, angularjs, thymeleaf

returning model object from spring controller to thymeleaf page, in thymeleaf page i am sending that object to angular controller tried like this

```
ng-controller="sessionController" th:attr="ng-init='init(\''+${session}+'\');'" - treating total object as a string
ng-controller="sessionController" th:attr="ng-init='init(${session});'" - parsing error

angularjs controller i wrote init method

function init(session){
    alert(JSON.stringify(session));
}
$scope.init = init;
```

any one can help me ,
how to send model object thymeleaf page to angular controller method.